# Wrap mode in nested load

Tags: ruby, namespaces, load

These are my test code:

1.rb:

```
module M
  A = 'Outer Constant'
  class C
    A = 'Inner Constant'
  end
  class M
    class C
      A="Inner Constant 2"
    end
  end
end
```

2.rb

```
load('1.rb')
```

3.rb

```
load('2.rb', true)
puts String.class
puts M::A
```

When I run `ruby 3.rb`, it returns:

```
class
Outer Constant
```

I think it should raise an error because of `load('', true)`，but it does not. Please tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of method `Kernel#load` is irrespective of the context it appears. Even if `2.rb` is loaded from `3.rb` under wrap mode, that has no effect on how `1.rb` is loaded in `2.rb`. `1.rb` is loaded without wrap mode, and hence under the ordinary namespace, which means `M::A` is callable from `3.rb`.

Comment: But 1.rb is loaded in 2.rb, and 2.rb is under wrap mode, why wrap mode doesn't have effects on 1.rb.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I wrote. That is how it works.

Comment: why did you write that way,that who asked for help,he himself is not understanding ? This comment box is for asking the clarifications.. and whenever someone will do such,you don't need to be rude..

Comment: I don't mean to. I am sorry.